# An expression for starting over

Tags: modismos

When you're telling someone that a plan didn't work out or one has to start over, one might say,

> Back to square one.

> Back to the drawing board.

Are there similar expressions in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguro. Una posibilidad sería: **borrón y cuenta nueva**.

> —La verdad que esta implementación A no está dando resultados de ninguna manera.
> —(hagamos) Borrón y cuenta nueva. Vamos con la implementación B.

Fuentes por ahí dicen algo así como que la expresión se usa para olvidarse de todo lo malo que le hicieron a uno. No lo sé, doy fe de que por acá el uso de tal expresión es exactamente el mismo que el que estás preguntando.

Answer (score 3):

Además de la opción que menciona @tac, otras expresiones similares pueden ser las siguientes:

- "*volver al punto de partida*" o "*volver a la casilla de salida*".

> Después de dos meses buscando patrocinadores, **volvemos a estar en el
> punto de partida**; tenemos una buena idea pero nadie que nos apoye
> económicamente.

- "Volver a empezar de cero"

> Nuestro plan no ha funcionado. Tenemos que **volver a empezar de cero** y
> evitar cometer los mismos errores.

Answer (score 3):

I support the other answers. Additionally, we can also use:

- barajar y dar de nuevo (literally, "shuffle and deal the cards again")

[Here](https://www.cervantesvirtual.com/buscador/?numresult=&orden=&avanzada=1&q=barajar%20y%20dar%20de%20nuevo&tipo=frase_exacta&ttitulo=&tautor=&tmateria=&busqueda=combinada&ftipo=&fformato=&fidioma=) we can find a couple of good examples:

- Como se desprende del trabajo, estos tres autores entendieron la vanguardia
  de manera diferente ya que el final de la Guerra Civil, la tragedia y el desarraigo los obligan a **barajar y dar de nuevo** y retomar prácticas que habían sido relegadas o se daban por proscritas [...]
- Si se me acepta la metáfora, **barajar y dar de nuevo** en la circunstancia del exilio, diré que Ramón siguió jugando, en un tiempo equivocado, su eterno solitario de vanguardista, nostálgico del arte por el arte que le había dado cobijo.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding a variant of an expression already mentioned, normally used as an exclamation at the very moment you realize you need to start all over again:

> — ¡Vuelta a empezar!

And stronger language may follow.